# Transparency multiple planes

Tags: web, three.js

Two planes are stacked on top of each other, with some distance between them, both with transparency enabled. The transparency of the top plain is not behaving as expected. When moving the mouse (trackball), sometimes you can't see the lowest plane through the upper plane.

Please see the problem here: [EXAMPLE CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/3S6Kh/25/)

The code:

```
  var scene = new THREE.Scene();

  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
  camera.position.x = 0;
  camera.position.y = 0;
  camera.position.z = 500;
  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      antialias: true
  });
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  //renderer.sortObjects = false;
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xFFFFFF);
  scene.add(light);

  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      transparent: true,
      side: THREE.DoubleSide,
      fog: false,
      color: 0xFF0000,
      opacity: 1.0
  });

  var cubeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(100, 300, 1, 1);
  var cubeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, material);
  scene.add(cubeMesh);


  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      transparent: true,
      side: THREE.DoubleSide,
      fog: false,
      color: 0x00FF00,
      opacity: 0.3
  });

  var cubeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(50, 50, 1, 1);
  var cubeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, material);
  cubeMesh.position.set(0, 100, 40);
  scene.add(cubeMesh);

  var controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
  controls.rotateSpeed = 1.0;
  controls.zoomSpeed = 3.0;
  controls.panSpeed = 3.0;
  controls.noZoom = false;
  controls.noPan = false;
  controls.noRotate = false;
  controls.staticMoving = false;
  controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.3;
  controls.keys = [65, 83, 68]; // [rotateKey, zoomKey, panKey]

  function render() {
      controls.update();

      camera.lookAt(scene.position);
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
      requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  render();
```

Answer (score 0):

This case is easily solvable by [just removing the `transparent: true` from the red material](http://jsfiddle.net/3S6Kh/27/)  (which is not supposed to be transparent).